# Find line and change background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to colour line one by on from my string

If the line start with `-` then line should be red and if the line start with `+` then line should be green.

I'm trying following one but How should I find the line is startwith `-` and colour the line.

```js
var data = "data {\n  name {\n-     data1; \n-     data2; \n+     data3; \n-     data4\n  }\n  abc {\n+     data5; \n-     data6\n  }\n}"


var res = data.replace(/data1|data2/gi, function myFunction(x){return '<span style="background-color:red;">'+x+'</span>'});

document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = res
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```js
var data = "data {\n  name {\n-     data1; \n-     data2;" + 
"\n+     data3; \n-     data4\n  }\n  abc {\n+     data5; " + 
"\n-     data6\n  }\n}"

var res = data.replace(/\n([-+][^\n]+)/gi, function myFunction(x) {
  var color = x.charAt(1) === '-' ? 'red' : 'green';
  return '<span style="background-color:'+ color + ';">'+x+'</span>'
});

document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Each line checked against `-` or `+` first, then both this character and the rest of the line are collected by replacer function.

Answer (score 2):

`+` has a special meaning in regular expressions. You need to escape that with `\`.

Also, you can select the complete line with `^` and `$` anchors.

```js
var data = "data {\n  name {\n-     data1; \n-     data2; \n+     data3; \n-     data4\n  }\n  abc {\n+     data5; \n-     data6\n  }\n}"


var res = data.replace(/^-.*$/gim, function myFunction(x) {
  return '<span style="background-color:red;">' + x + '</span>'
});

res = res.replace(/^\+.*$/gim, function myFunction(x) {
  return '<span style="background-color:green;">' + x + '</span>'
});

document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = res
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a slightly different regex, `/^[-][\s]+(.*)$/gm`. Notice the capturing group `(.*)`, which I am using to narrow down to the string `data1` or `data2`, and only highlight that part in the string (using `$1` variables).

Of course, if you don't need such fine grained highlight, others answers already do that.

```js
var data = "data {\n  name {\n-     data1; \n-     data2; \n+     data3; \n-     data4\n  }\n  abc {\n+     data5; \n-     data6\n  }\n}"


var res = data.replace(/^[-][\s]+(.*)$/gm, function myFunction(x, $1) {
    return x.replace($1,'<span style="background-color:red;">' + $1 + '</span>');
  })
  .replace(/^[+][\s]+(.*)$/gm, function myFunction(x, $1) {
    return  x.replace($1,'<span style="background-color:lightgreen;">' + $1 + '</span>');
  });

document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = res
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```